# I am calling an external js file however it does nothing. Am I calling it wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="TEXTBOX1_ID"></input>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add"onclick="add_element_to_array()"></input>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Display" onclick="display_array()"</input>

<script src="js/app-functions.js"</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the above code contains two buttons and onclick they use a function from a js file. However once I press any of the bottoms it does nothing a piece of text is meant to appear, I don't think it is my js code as It very simple and I have made sure it's not a syntax error.

Comment: You have several errors that https://validator.w3.org would highlight.

Comment: What error does your javascript console print out?

Comment: I used validator.w3.org to fix the errors. however the js file still does nothing?

Comment: @JimCode this question doesn't belong here

Answer (score -1):

you missed to `>` in `script`.it didn't include file .

**corrected:**

```
<script src="js/app-functions.js"></script>
```